# pandas not reading all the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a mixed effect model with data in CSV form.
Dataset (https://github.com/nisengweregis/mixed-effects-model/blob/master/mixed_effects.csv)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import sklearn as sk
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

from math import sqrt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import statsmodels.api as sm




df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\E0434232\Documents\PlatformIO\Python DS\mixed_effects.csv")


# model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula('score ~ exercise_hrs + age + gender', df, groups =df['trainer'])
# result = model.fit()
# result.summary()
```

Loading the data into a df doesn't give any error however while creating the model, I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-68-7f704114eb8c> in <module>
    ----> 1 model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula('score ~ exercise_hrs + age + gender', df, groups =df['trainer'])
          2 result = model.fit()
          3 result.summary()
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, re_formula, vc_formula, subset, use_sparse, missing, *args, **kwargs)
       1039         kwargs["exog_vc"] = exog_vc
       1040         kwargs["groups"] = groups
    -> 1041         mod = super(MixedLM, cls).from_formula(
       1042             formula, data, *args, **kwargs)
       1043 
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, drop_cols, *args, **kwargs)
        193                        'formula': formula,  # attach formula for unpckling
        194                        'design_info': design_info})
    --> 195         mod = cls(endog, exog, *args, **kwargs)
        196         mod.formula = formula
        197 
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, groups, exog_re, exog_vc, use_sqrt, missing, **kwargs)
        787         # list of arrays, corresponding to the groups.
        788         group_labels = list(set(groups))
    --> 789         group_labels.sort()
        790         row_indices = dict((s, []) for s in group_labels)
        791         for i, g in enumerate(groups):
    
    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I suspected it may be due to dtype of the column 'Trainer' so i tried changing it to 'str' and 'Category'

```
df['trainer']=df['trainer'].astype('category')
    df.dtypes
    
        student_id       float64
exercise_hrs     float64
books            float64
score            float64
gender           float64
trainer         category
age              float64
dtype: object
```

But then I get an Index error:

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-7f704114eb8c> in <module>
----> 1 model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula('score ~ exercise_hrs + age + gender', df, groups =df['trainer'])
      2 result = model.fit()
      3 result.summary()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, re_formula, vc_formula, subset, use_sparse, missing, *args, **kwargs)
   1039         kwargs["exog_vc"] = exog_vc
   1040         kwargs["groups"] = groups
-> 1041         mod = super(MixedLM, cls).from_formula(
   1042             formula, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1043 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, drop_cols, *args, **kwargs)
    193                        'formula': formula,  # attach formula for unpckling
    194                        'design_info': design_info})
--> 195         mod = cls(endog, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    196         mod.formula = formula
    197 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, groups, exog_re, exog_vc, use_sqrt, missing, **kwargs)
    796 
    797         # Split the data by groups
--> 798         self.endog_li = self.group_list(self.endog)
    799         self.exog_li = self.group_list(self.exog)
    800         self.exog_re_li = self.group_list(self.exog_re)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in group_list(self, array)
   1097 
   1098         if array.ndim == 1:
-> 1099             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k]])
   1100                     for k in self.group_labels]
   1101         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\mixed_linear_model.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1097 
   1098         if array.ndim == 1:
-> 1099             return [np.array(array[self.row_indices[k]])
   1100                     for k in self.group_labels]
   1101         else:

IndexError: index 105 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 105
```

In the csv file the data looks ok and there are no missing values either. But apparently pandas is not liking the data after the row 103. Could you please tell what is wrong with the data?

Comment: the csv in your link only has 104 data rows, so 105 is out of bounds.
The upper error elicited by `group_labels.sort()` can probably get solved by replacing the grouping-strings by numbers. Then they are 'sortable'

Comment: can u also add the packages u imported. it will help others to evaluate

Comment: I have double checked and there are 105 rows in the csv file. It's surprising that you says there are 104. But as I mentioned earlier, the pandas manages to read only 103 rows. I wonder what's wrong with the last two rows

Comment: By "replacing the grouping-strings by numbers" you mean changing the column names to numbers? or do you mean something else?

Comment: @phoenix I have updated the code with imported packages